# Centering relative div to background image

Tags: html, css, image, center

I would like to know how to get a Div Box centred and relative to the background image so it keeps responsive? The div box should be inside the white box. E.g. http://sendvid.com/t4d85cqe

```
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  background-image: url("assets/handheld_bg_white.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.overlay-box {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You've not mentioned if this needs to be pure CSS, but if you're able to use Bootstrap 4, then you can do it as follows:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div>
        Hello world
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in css by using "display: flex", "justify-content: center" and "align-items: center" properties. Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yr510dcb/ and below is some code example:

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  background-image: url("assets/handheld_bg_white.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.background {
  display: flex;           /* establish flex container */
  justify-content: center; /* center items vertically */
  align-items: center;     /* center items horizontally */
  height: 50vw;
  width: 80vw;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 100;
  
}

.overlay-box {
  display: flex;           /* establish flex container in case its content needs to be centered */
  justify-content: center; /* center items vertically in case its content needs to be centered */
  align-items: center;     /* center items horizontally in case its content needs to be centered */
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 25vw;
  width: 25vw;
  background-color: white;
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class = "background">
  <div class = "overlay-box">
  </div>
</div>
```

You use these properties in the parent div (in this case "background") to center its content - the child div ("overlay-box"). I have added the "flex" and "center" attributes in the child as well, so again its content get centered, but you can remove it without affecting the centering of the "overlay-box" itself.

If you have an background image, you can wrap the image inside the parent div, e.g.

```
<div class = "background">
  <img src="/image.png" class="responsive">  /* image location - in this case a local image */
  <div class = "overlay-box">
  </div>
</div>
```

and add a responsive class in css to make it responsive and the size of the parent:

```
.responsive {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```